# Problem resolving Nuget Packages in Devops Build Agent due to Certificate issues

Tags: nuget, certificate, devops, trusted

We are hosting DevOps Server on Premise with one Build Agent. The Build agent behave strange if i start running NuGet restore against .NET 5.0 Project. In special against a Test Project Template from VS2019 (MS-Test Testproject). As soon as i run the Nuget restore it failed with a loot of 'NU3028' 'NU3034' 'NU3037' issues. I already updated the nuget.config but it looks like nothing is working.

OS: Windows Server 2019 V.1809 Build 17763.2300

Devops: Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1 V. 18.181.31626.1

Nuget: 6.0.0 (x64)

Devops Pipe:
[Devops Pipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyOMO.png)

Output: [Pipe Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhLhB.png)

Nuget.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="VollmerPackages" value="https://devops/Vollmer/_packaging/VollmerPackages/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
<trustedSigners>
  <author name="Microsoft">
    <certificate fingerprint="3F9001EA83C560D712C24CF213C3D312CB3BFF51EE89435D3430BD06B5D0EECE" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="false" />
    <certificate fingerprint="AA12DA22A49BCE7D5C1AE64CC1F3D892F150DA76140F210ABD2CBFFCA2C18A27" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="false" />
  </author>
  <repository name="nuget.org" serviceIndex="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json">
    <certificate fingerprint="0E5F38F57DC1BCC806D8494F4F90FBCEDD988B46760709CBEEC6F4219AA6157D" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="false" />
    <certificate fingerprint="5A2901D6ADA3D18260B9C6DFE2133C95D74B9EEF6AE0E5DC334C8454D1477DF4" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="false" />
  </repository>
</trustedSigners>
</configuration>
```

if i run Nuget restore local on my VS PC, the restore runs without any errors. If i run it on the build agent server there are tons of certificate issues.

CMD output Nuget restore (build agent server):

```
    Package 'System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Signature Hash Algorithm: SHA256
Package 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Signature Hash Algorithm: SHA256
NU3034: Package 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': This package is signed but not by a trusted signer.
Package 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':
Signature type: Repository
Package 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Service index: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Package 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Owners: dotnetframework, Microsoft
Package 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Verifying the repository primary signature with certificate:

Package 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   Subject Name: CN=NuGet.org Repository by Microsoft, O=NuGet.org Repository by Microsoft, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
NU3034: Package 'System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': This package is signed but not by a trusted signer.
Package 'System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':
Signature type: Repository
Package 'System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Service index: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Package 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   SHA1 hash: 8FB6D7FCF7AD49EB774446EFE778B33365BB7BFB
Package 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   SHA256 hash: 0E5F38F57DC1BCC806D8494F4F90FBCEDD988B46760709CBEEC6F4219AA6157D
Package 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   Issued by: CN=DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Code Signing CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
Package 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   Valid from: 10.04.2018 02:00:00 to 14.04.2021 14:00:00
NU3037: Package 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature validity period has expired.
Package 'System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Owners: dotnetframework, Microsoft
Package 'System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Verifying the repository primary signature with certificate:

Package 'System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   Subject Name: CN=NuGet.org Repository by Microsoft, O=NuGet.org Repository by Microsoft, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Package 'System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   SHA1 hash: 8FB6D7FCF7AD49EB774446EFE778B33365BB7BFB
Package 'System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   SHA256 hash: 0E5F38F57DC1BCC806D8494F4F90FBCEDD988B46760709CBEEC6F4219AA6157D
Package 'System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   Issued by: CN=DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Code Signing CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
Package 'System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   Valid from: 10.04.2018 02:00:00 to 14.04.2021 14:00:00
NU3037: Package 'System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature validity period has expired.
Package 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Timestamp: 05.10.2018 16:36:21

Package 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Verifying repository primary signature's timestamp with timestamping service certificate:
  Subject Name: CN=Symantec SHA256 TimeStamping Signer - G2, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
  SHA1 hash: 625AEC3AE4EDA1D169C4EE909E85B3BBC61076D3
  SHA256 hash: CF7AC17AD047ECD5FDC36822031B12D4EF078B6F2B4C5E6BA41F8FF2CF4BAD67
  Issued by: CN=Symantec SHA256 TimeStamping CA, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
  Valid from: 02.01.2017 01:00:00 to 02.04.2028 01:59:59

NU3028: Package 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature's timestamping certificate is not trusted by the trust provider.
Package 'System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Timestamp: 13.12.2018 23:56:51

Package 'System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Verifying repository primary signature's timestamp with timestamping service certificate:
  Subject Name: CN=Symantec SHA256 TimeStamping Signer - G2, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
  SHA1 hash: 625AEC3AE4EDA1D169C4EE909E85B3BBC61076D3
  SHA256 hash: CF7AC17AD047ECD5FDC36822031B12D4EF078B6F2B4C5E6BA41F8FF2CF4BAD67
  Issued by: CN=Symantec SHA256 TimeStamping CA, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
  Valid from: 02.01.2017 01:00:00 to 02.04.2028 01:59:59

NU3028: Package 'System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature's timestamping certificate is not trusted by the trust provider.
Package 'System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Signature Hash Algorithm: SHA256
NU3034: Package 'System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': This package is signed but not by a trusted signer.
Package 'System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':
Signature type: Repository
Package 'System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Service index: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Package 'System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Owners: dotnetframework, Microsoft
Package 'System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Verifying the repository primary signature with certificate:

Package 'runtime.ubuntu.14.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Signature Hash Algorithm: SHA256
Package 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Signature Hash Algorithm: SHA256
NU3034: Package 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': This package is signed but not by a trusted signer.
Package 'System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Signature Hash Algorithm: SHA256
Package 'System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Signature Hash Algorithm: SHA256
NU3034: Package 'System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': This package is signed but not by a trusted signer.
Package 'System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   Subject Name: CN=NuGet.org Repository by Microsoft, O=NuGet.org Repository by Microsoft, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
NU3034: Package 'runtime.ubuntu.14.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': This package is signed but not by a trusted signer.
Package 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':
Signature type: Repository
NU3034: Package 'System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': This package is signed but not by a trusted signer.
Package 'System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':
Signature type: Repository
Package 'System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Service index: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Package 'System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Owners: dotnetframework, Microsoft
Package 'System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Verifying the repository primary signature with certificate:

Package 'System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   Subject Name: CN=NuGet.org Repository by Microsoft, O=NuGet.org Repository by Microsoft, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Package 'System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   SHA1 hash: 8FB6D7FCF7AD49EB774446EFE778B33365BB7BFB
Package 'System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   SHA256 hash: 0E5F38F57DC1BCC806D8494F4F90FBCEDD988B46760709CBEEC6F4219AA6157D
Package 'System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   SHA1 hash: 8FB6D7FCF7AD49EB774446EFE778B33365BB7BFB
Package 'System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   SHA256 hash: 0E5F38F57DC1BCC806D8494F4F90FBCEDD988B46760709CBEEC6F4219AA6157D
Package 'System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':
Signature type: Repository
Package 'System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Service index: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Package 'System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Owners: dotnetframework, Microsoft
Package 'System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Verifying the repository primary signature with certificate:
....
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Btw it doesn't even change if i use dotnet restore insted of nuget restore. both behave same on server. Latest SDK 6.0.100 is installed on build server....

**UPDATE:
Found a way to ignore all upcomming Issues relating the Certificates by add all SHA256 fingerprints to 'trustedSigners' block and by setting the 'allowUntrustedRott' to true, i ignore the errors and the packages getting installed. This is still an ugly workaround dealing with untrusted Certificates but it's the only possibility i figured out so far.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
      <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
      
    </packageSources>
    <config>
      <add key="signatureValidationMode" value="accept" />
    </config>
    <packageRestore>
        <add key="enabled" value="True" />
        <add key="automatic" value="True" />
    </packageRestore>
    <trustedSigners>
      <author name="Microsoft">
        <certificate fingerprint="3F9001EA83C560D712C24CF213C3D312CB3BFF51EE89435D3430BD06B5D0EECE" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="true" />
        <certificate fingerprint="AA12DA22A49BCE7D5C1AE64CC1F3D892F150DA76140F210ABD2CBFFCA2C18A27" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="true" />
      </author>
      <repository name="nuget.org" serviceIndex="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json">
        <certificate fingerprint="0E5F38F57DC1BCC806D8494F4F90FBCEDD988B46760709CBEEC6F4219AA6157D" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="true" />
        <certificate fingerprint="5A2901D6ADA3D18260B9C6DFE2133C95D74B9EEF6AE0E5DC334C8454D1477DF4" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="true" />
        <certificate fingerprint=" CF7AC17AD047ECD5FDC36822031B12D4EF078B6F2B4C5E6BA41F8FF2CF4BAD67" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="true" />
        <certificate fingerprint="C474CE76007D02394E0DA5E4DE7C14C680F9E282013CFEF653EF5DB71FDF61F8" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="true" />
      </repository>
    </trustedSigners>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Issuer of the `Symantec SHA256 TimeStamping Signer - G2,` is her: https://crt.sh/?q=Symantec+SHA256+TimeStamping+CA and was issued itself by https://crt.sh/?caid=1110

Put the first one in the `ROOT` store of the `LocalMachine` and the second on in `IntermediateCA`.

Seems like the CTLs updates are disabled: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn265983(v=ws.11)

Comment: I will give it a try but my main concern are related to the Microsoft certificates issues earlier this year. Nuget said the new version would solve the issues with the outdated Microsoft certificates but it doesn't work.